# How to add plus(+) sign in every row of a column using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a column containing phone numbers. I want to add plus(+) sign in the beginning of every phone number.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Phone = CONCAT('+', Phone)
```

This is the query I'm using to insert any other character, but it doesn't seem to work with + sign. It says **0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 4023  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0**, which means nothing has changed.

Even if I do `SET Phone = CONCAT('+91', Phone)`, only **91** is being inserted and not the plus sign.

Comment: Which Mysql version are you using? I cannot reproduce this in a "clean" mysql database – please see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3fe5f/1

Comment: @SergeyMartynov I'm new to whole sql stuff so I could be wrong but I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: This would seem to be an odd way of handling phone numbers, if you're adding a `+` to all rows regardless then just handle this in your presentation layer; more common is storing a phone number and its countrycode prefix as two separate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood what's going on here. Your `Table` is probably using integer data type for `Phone` column. In this case `Phone = CONCAT('+91', Phone)` implicitly converts value to character type, adds leading "+" but then converts it back to integer type to store value.

You might want to do something like

```sql
ALTER TABLE `Table` MODIFY Phone Varchar(100);
```

(please choose column type accordingly)

I reproduced it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3a651/1